# Test for Node Emptiness

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following two xml nodes:

```
<CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="3">
  <TableBodyCenterBold>
    <A ID="pgfId-179932"/>
  </TableBodyCenterBold>
</CELL>

<CELL ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="6">
  <TableBodyCenterBold>
    <A ID="pgfId-179938"/>
    Body Tensile Capacity (lb)
  </TableBodyCenterBold>
</CELL>
```

Apparently, the first node `<CELL>` differs from the second `<CELL>` in that the `<TableBodyCenterBold>` of the first one doesn't have any text.

I have tried the following XPath, but all failed:

```
<xsl:when test="string-length(CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold[1]/text()) &gt; 0">
```

or

```
<xsl:when test="CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold[1]/text()!=''">
```

Could experts offer some help on how to efficiently differentiate the first node from the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You must take into account the existing white-space - only text-node children** of `TableBodyCenterBold`.

**A correct expression that tests for "emptyness" and ignores whitespace-only text nodes is**:

```
CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold[1][not(string-length(normalize-space()) > 0)]
```

This evaluates to `true()` exactly when the first `TableBodyCenterBold` child of the first `CELL` child of the current node, has a string value, which when normalized results in the empty string.

Comment: thank you so much! Only you provide the good solution and did see the essence of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold[1]/A[not(text())]
```

or

```
CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold/A[not(node())]
```

Comment: @Kevin - did you use match or test?

Answer (score 1):

Krakover's answer is the right idea, but I believe he's erroneously included the `A` node-test step. I believe you are instead looking for:

```
CELL[1]/TableBodyCenterBold[not(text())]
```

The text in your example is inside the `TableBodyCenterBold` element, not the `A` element.

Also, since this is a relative XPath (it doesn't start with `/`), you might double-check that this XPath is being evaluated against the context node you were expecting.